# Issues building Android gradle project: Task :buildSrc:compileGroovy FAILED

Tags: java, android, groovy, build.gradle, gradlew

I am trying to build an Android SDK on my Windows machine. I upgraded my Java to latest 64-bit JDK (21) and when running `.\gradlew.bat core:assembleCoreDebug`, I get these errors.

How to resolve it?

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :buildSrc:compileGroovy FAILED
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileGroovy'.
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\mobile\android\buildSrc\src\main\groovy\Javadoc.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 65

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Comment: change jdk to 17

Comment: Yeah it fixed it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to delete the following folders:

1. `.gradle`
2. `.idea`
3. `build`

and then sync and build.